# Why doesn't Stack Overflow highlight the “get” and “set” keywords? (C#)

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Ok, сontinuing the theme of highlighting. Why doesn't Stack Overflow highlight the "get" and "set" keywords? Even with `<!-- language: lang-c# -->`:

```c#
public class Something
{
    private readonly int field;
    public int Property { get; protected set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** there is also an issue with "readonly".

Comment: It is not Stackoverflow fault. SO uses third party library (google prettify) for highlighting. Tell them about this problem, and, I guess, as far as google release new version, you'll get highlighting here.

Comment: Because [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=70) is still open (sort of; identifying the properties in the lexer to properly highlight the `get`/`set` is non-trivial).

Comment: @om-nom-nom But those libraries are either open source or tunable.

Comment: @Lorond Yes, but I suppose SE doesn't want to maintain an own clone/fork of the library when the improvement could go into the main release.

Comment: SO is (quite rightly) telling you that properties are a lousy idea, and you shouldn't use them.

Comment: @Jerry: `[citation-required]` I can think of lots of reasons to use properties when you're writing C# code, if only because the .NET Framework does this extensively itself.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Yes, .NET is lousy design. You can cite me, if you want. When it comes to designing code, I'm obviously a much better authority than whoever made the decisions in that design! :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It's hard to tell if you're joking or not. I like you're style...or do I?

Comment: @BrianGideon: I usually don't know for sure either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim noted in comments, this is something you'll need to take up with the [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) folks to get this implemented (if it is even possible and desirable).