# Error in C# syntax highlighting

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed a glitch in the syntax highlighting of C# code on Stack Overflow. The [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag's standard highlighting doesn't include the keywords `using` and `namespace`

However, when adding the language directive `<!-- language: lang-csharp -->`, those are highlighted. So I request to add this directive to every post in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag.

Here's the rendering screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Link to an example? The syntax highlighting works fine for me every time.

Comment: `lang-csharp` does not exist. You're seeing the default syntax highlighting by using that. The [tag:c#] tag is set to use `lang-cs`.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297279/nested-namespaces - The keyword `namespace` isn't highlighted.

Comment: @animuson `lang-cs` doesn't work for some keywords. But the `lang-csharp` works.

Comment: @CodyGray Added example

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati - Have a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/187824) for more details. `lang-cs` or `lang-c#` (tag name) can be used.

Comment: @Sri: Like I said, `lang-csharp` **does not exist**. By using that it's reverting to default. If those keywords happen to get highlighted, that's merely coincidence.

Comment: @animuson I've added the rendering screenshot. Since this is working, could you change that to `lang-csharp`?

Comment: @Sri: I can't change it to an identifier that doesn't exist. We're kindof limited to the list of identifiers available... I really don't know how else to make you understand that `lang-csharp` is not real.

Comment: @animuson Sorry. I'm just saying that this is working. Even the Google's page on it says to use `lang-cs`. Maybe I'll file a issue on their site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the identifier you use in the language directive

- starts with `lang-`
- but is not listed under "**Language codes**" in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970)

you would get the default syntax highlighting behavior.

Specifically, invalid identifiers such as `lang-csharp`, `lang-doesnotexist`, and `lang-iambanana` are treated as `lang-default`.

The default syntax highlighting (`lang-default`) works by highlighting *any* keyword from *any* predefined keyword list in [**prettify.js**](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js). This means it can "grab" keywords from multiple languages, even though the code is written in a single language.

*== End of TL;DR region ==*

Some examples to illustrate what I'm saying

### Example 1: `lang-cs`

This markdown

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->

    public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

renders as

[image: syntax highlighting with lang-cs]

### Example 2: `lang-i-am-a-banana`

This markdown

```
<!-- language: lang-i-am-a-banana -->

    public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

renders as

[image: syntax highlighting with lang-i-am-a-banana]

### The difference between `lang-cs` and `lang-i-am-a-banana`

If we compare Examples 1 and 2, note that `bool` and `get` which was not highlighted with `lang-cs` was highlighted with `lang-i-am-a-banana`.

Looking at the C#'s keyword list

```js
var FLOW_CONTROL_KEYWORDS = ["break,continue,do,else,for,if,return,while"];
var C_KEYWORDS = [FLOW_CONTROL_KEYWORDS,"auto,case,char,const,default," + 
      "double,enum,extern,float,goto,inline,int,long,register,short,signed," +
      "sizeof,static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,void,volatile"];
var COMMON_KEYWORDS = [C_KEYWORDS,"catch,class,delete,false,import," +
      "new,operator,private,protected,public,this,throw,true,try,typeof"];
var CSHARP_KEYWORDS = [COMMON_KEYWORDS,
      "abstract,as,base,bool,by,byte,checked,decimal,delegate,descending," +
      "dynamic,event,finally,fixed,foreach,from,group,implicit,in,interface," +
      "internal,into,is,let,lock,null,object,out,override,orderby,params," +
      "partial,readonly,ref,sbyte,sealed,stackalloc,string,select,uint,ulong," +
      "unchecked,unsafe,ushort,var,virtual,where"];
```

- I'm not sure why `bool` was not highlighted with `lang-cs`, maybe SO/SE is not using the most recent revision of [**prettify.js**](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js)? The latest revision at the time of writing, [r303](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/diff?spec=svn303&r=303&format=side&path=/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js&old_path=/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js&old=292) added `bool` to C#'s keyword list.
- `get` is most definitely not in C#'s keyword list, even in the latest revision

*Assuming that SO/SE is using an older revision*, in `lang-i-am-a-banana` mode, `bool` is "grabbed" from C++'s keyword list

```js
var CPP_KEYWORDS = [COMMON_KEYWORDS,"alignof,align_union,asm,axiom,bool," +
      "concept,concept_map,const_cast,constexpr,decltype,delegate," +
      "dynamic_cast,explicit,export,friend,generic,late_check," +
      "mutable,namespace,nullptr,property,reinterpret_cast,static_assert," +
      "static_cast,template,typeid,typename,using,virtual,where"];
```

in `lang-i-am-a-banana` mode, `get` is "grabbed" from JavaScript's keyword list

```js
var JSCRIPT_KEYWORDS = [COMMON_KEYWORDS,
      "debugger,eval,export,function,get,null,set,undefined,var,with," +
      "Infinity,NaN"];
```

### Invalid identifiers that don't start with `lang-`

The fallback to `lang-default` isn't triggered if your identifier doesn't start with `lang-`

```
<!-- language: i-am-a-banana -->

    public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

renders as

[image: syntax-highlighting with i-am-a-banana]

or renders according to language tag the question is using. In this case, the language directive simply gets silently ignored.

Answer (score 7):

Like [animuson said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189802/error-in-c-syntax-highlighting#comment586835_189802), the correct identifier for the C# language is `lang-cs`. Alternatively, you could use the name of the tag, in which case it would be `c#`. This is all documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), which gives the identifiers for each language.

What you're using (`lang-csharp`) is no different than `lang-apples-and-bananas` or `lang-invalid-language`. Because there is no `lang-csharp` identifier, you're just getting the default syntax highlighting, used when no (valid) language is specified.

So the *real* problem here is that `namespace` is not highlighted as a keyword when the C# syntax highlighting is applied. [We've had this problem before with the `virtual` keyword](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102946/syntax-highlighting-doesnt-detect-virtual-as-a-keyword-for-c), and [the `get` and `set` keywords](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129666/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-highlight-the-get-and-set-keywords-c), and [the new C# 5.0 keywords](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150295/c-syntax-highlighting-doesnt-highlight-newer-keywords-including-await-and).

The same answer applies to this as it did to all of those previous cases: Stack Exchange outsources syntax highlighting to [Google Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), so if there's a bug in the implementation, it's their bug.

Looking at the code, the problem is fairly obvious. In the current revision of [prettify.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js), where the keywords are defined for various supported languages, `namespace` is missing from the C# list:

```
  var FLOW_CONTROL_KEYWORDS = ["break,continue,do,else,for,if,return,while"];
  var C_KEYWORDS = [FLOW_CONTROL_KEYWORDS,"auto,case,char,const,default," + 
      "double,enum,extern,float,goto,int,long,register,short,signed,sizeof," +
      "static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,void,volatile"];
  var COMMON_KEYWORDS = [C_KEYWORDS,"catch,class,delete,false,import," +
      "new,operator,private,protected,public,this,throw,true,try,typeof"];
  var CPP_KEYWORDS = [COMMON_KEYWORDS,"alignof,align_union,asm,axiom,bool," +
      "concept,concept_map,const_cast,constexpr,decltype," +
      "dynamic_cast,explicit,export,friend,inline,late_check," +
      "mutable,namespace,nullptr,reinterpret_cast,static_assert,static_cast," +
      "template,typeid,typename,using,virtual,where"];
  var JAVA_KEYWORDS = [COMMON_KEYWORDS,
      "abstract,boolean,byte,extends,final,finally,implements,import," +
      "instanceof,null,native,package,strictfp,super,synchronized,throws," +
      "transient"];
  var CSHARP_KEYWORDS = [JAVA_KEYWORDS,
      "as,base,by,checked,decimal,delegate,descending,dynamic,event," +
      "fixed,foreach,from,group,implicit,in,interface,internal,into,is,lock," +
      "object,out,override,orderby,params,partial,readonly,ref,sbyte,sealed," +
      "stackalloc,string,select,uint,ulong,unchecked,unsafe,ushort,var," +
      "virtual,where"];
```

The only language that has a namespace keyword is C++, and the C++ keywords are not imported to the list of C# keywords. The fix is therefore quite simple, it just needs to be brought to the attention of someone with commit rights to the source code.

Comment: I'll file an issue on it. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @CodyGray The equivalent to `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` is `<!-- language: c# -->`. `<-- language: lang-c# -->`, mentioned in your post, would trigger the default behavior much like `<!-- language: lang-csharp -->` would.

Comment: @doubleDown Don't miss the "edit" link ;-) Sometimes my fingers get carried away.

Comment: It's interesting that C# keywords contain the Java keywords. Because some of them (like "transient", "package", "strictfp", "super", etc...) are certainly not C# keywords...

Comment: Indeed, it looks like more of them are *not* C# keywords than *are*. Keyword-based highlighting seems intuitively wrong to me anyway, but I guess it's by far the easiest way of doing it. Just raises the maintenance costs substantially.